# How to set day of alarm in android by using AlarmClock

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm

we can create alarm with intent in android

```
        Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm"); 
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 23); 
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 11);
```

we want to add day property  while creating an alarm .  However , AlarmClock does not contain a property about "Extra_Day_Week" so we did not set day of alarm. Do you have any idea to solve this problem by using intent ve alarmclock

Thank your creative response

Comment: The `AlarmClock` provider doesn't have the capability to specify the day. Are you trying to get an installed Alarm application to start ringing at the specified time, or are you looking to be notified when such a time happens (so that you can start your own user-facing alarm, for example?) In the latter case, you'd use `AlarmManager` not `AlarmClock`.

Comment: it is very strange because default app in android supplies alarm with 7 days (not specified time buy only 7 days) . Alarmclock allows us to change hours and minutes, why does not Alarmclock allow to change alarm with 7 days .

Comment: `AlarmClock` is a content provider and is separate from the default app. Different third-party apps (and the system app) can choose to use the `AlarmClock` content provider by handling a few of the intents. Perhaps if you edit your question with your use-case, people will be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

May this Help you:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(2012,2,8,18,16);// instead of these lines you can use below lines in comment

    //cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    //cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);
    //cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: we tried this code , but it works without errors , it does not add any alarm to default alarm app in android. Normally code that we shared put a alarm in default alarm app in android. we see it. Thank your response

Comment: Try the edited code buddy... and make sure you have given permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Lucky: buddy keep your set alarm code in a thread and execute that thread after a interval of every 4 hours.. it will set your alarm 6 times a day..

Answer (score 1):

You might forgot permission to add in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: we said we can create alarm without day property. we added permissions in manifest. Thank your response

Answer (score 0):

The property is called [EXTRA_DAYS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_DAYS):

You can use it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> alarmDays = new ArrayList<>();
alarmDays.add(Calendar.MONDAY);
alarmDays.add(Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
alarmDays.add(Calendar.FRIDAY);

Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, alarmDays);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 23);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 11);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");    
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_VIBRATE, true);

startActivity(i);
```

Any other users spotting this, don't forget to request permission! (in the manifest)

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```